# Is my derivation of the Bellman equation for $q_{\pi}$ in terms of $p(s'|s,a)$ and $r(s,a)$ correct?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, value-functions, sutton-barto, bellman-equations

I have done exercise 3.29 from Sutton and Barto and I'd like to check if it's correct. Here's the exercise:

> Rewrite the Bellman equation for the function $q_{\pi}$ in terms of the three argument function $p$  (3.4) and the two-argument function $r$  (3.5).

Here are the 2 functions:

(3.4) :

$$p(s'|s,a) = P(S_t=s'|S_{t-1}=s,A_{t-1}=a)=\sum_{r\in\mathcal{R}}p(s',r|s,a)$$

3.5:

$$r(s,a) = E[R_t|S_{t-1}=s,A_{t-1}=a]=\sum_{r\in\mathcal{R}}r\sum_{s'\in\mathcal{S}}p(s',r|s,a)$$

Here's my solution. Is this derivation correct?

$$q_\pi(s,a)  = \\ E_{\pi}[G_{t+1}|S_t=s,A_t=a]= E_{\pi}[R_{t+1} + \gamma G_{t+1} |S_t=s,A_t=a]= \\ E_[R_{t+1}|S_t=s,A_t=a]+\gamma E_{\pi}[G_{t+1}|S_t=s,A_t=a] = \\ \sum_{s',r}p(s',r|s,a)r+\gamma \sum_{s'}p(s'|s,a)v_{\pi}(s') = \\ r(s,a) + \gamma \sum_{s'} p(s'|s,a) \sum_{a'}q(a'|s')\pi(a'|s')$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work all looks correct to me. But I don't have the exercise 3.29 in my book, so I can't read the question for myself. It's not clear to me whether your last line or second to last line should be considered as the answer.